# how to get text from child element from console

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the  which is in

as you can see:

```
<p class="jmbadge">
   <strong>xxx</strong>
   <br>
   <span class="field-value">text!</span>
</p>
```

I'm trying to get the `<span>`

this is inside a website and I want to take the text of `<span>` via the console (Google Chrome)

here is what I tried:

```
const jminfo = document.getElementsByClassName("jminfo");
const span = jminfo.querySelector('span');
console.log(span);
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jminfo.querySelector is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const jminfo = document.getElementsByClassName("jmbadge")[0];

const span = jminfo.querySelector('span');
console.log(span);
```

```html
<p class="jmbadge">
   <strong>xxx</strong>
   <br>
   <span class="field-value">text!</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you selected a punch of elements with a class name but didn’t specify wich elements from these elements list.

Try to use:

```
const span = document.querySelector('.jminfo > span');
console.log(span);
```

but in case you know the index of the element in the document you can use:

```
const jminfo = document.getElementsByClassName("jmbadge")[N];
// n = the index
const span = jminfo.querySelector('span');
console.log(span);
```